# n-gram similarity for the words in the file

Tags: java, similarity

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package sim;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeMath.max;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class Sim {
    public String[][] bigramizedWords = new String[500][100];
    public String[] words = new String[500];
    public File file1 = new File("file1.txt");
    public File file2 = new File("file2.txt");
    public int tracker = 0;
    public double matches = 0;
    public double denominator = 0; //This will hold the sum of the bigrams of the 2 words
    public double res;
    public double results;

    public Scanner a;
    public PrintWriter pw1;
    public Sim(){
        intialize();
       // bigramize();
        results = max(res);
        System.out.println("\n\nThe Bigram Similarity value between " + words[0] + " and " + words[1] + " is " + res + ".");
        pw1.close();

    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sim si=new Sim();
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
    public void intialize() {
        int j[]=new int[35];
        try {

            File file1=new File("input.txt");
            File file2=new File("out.txt");
            Scanner a = new Scanner(file1);
            PrintWriter pw1= new PrintWriter(file2);
            int i=0,count = 0;

            while (a.hasNext()) {

                java.lang.String gram = a.next();
                if(gram.startsWith("question")|| gram.endsWith("?"))
                {
                    count=0;
                    count-=1;
                }

                if(gram.startsWith("[")||gram.startsWith("answer")||gram.endsWith(" ") )
                {
                    //pw1.println(count);
                    j[i++]=count;

                    count=0;
                    //pw1.println(gram);
                    //System.out.println(count);

                }
                else
                {
                    // System.out.println(count);
                    count+=1;
//System.out.println(count + " " + gram);

                }
       int line=gram.length();
    int sa_length;
                        //int[] j = null;
            int refans_length=j[1];
            //System.out.println(refans_length);
            for(int k=2;k<=35;k++)
               // System.out.println(j[k]);
            //System.out.println(refans_length);
            for(int m=2;m<=33;m++)

            {
                sa_length=j[2];
                //System.out.println(sa_length);

                for(int s=0;s<=refans_length;s++)
                {
                    for(int l=0;l<=sa_length;l++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x <= line - 2; x++) {
                            int tracker = 0;
                    bigramizedWords[tracker][x] = gram.substring(x, x + 2);
                    System.out.println(gram.substring(x, x + 2) + "");
                    //bigramize(); 
                }
              // bigramize(); 

            }
        }

    }
            bigramize();
         words[tracker] = gram;
                tracker++;

            }
            //pw1.close();

    }


    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sim.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void bigramize() {
        //for(int p=0;p<=sa_length;p++)
        denominator = (words[0].length() - 1) + (words[1].length() - 1);
        for (int k = 0; k < bigramizedWords[0].length; k++) {
            if (bigramizedWords[0][k] != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < bigramizedWords[1].length; i++) {
                    if (bigramizedWords[1][i] != null) {
                        if (bigramizedWords[0][k].equals(bigramizedWords[1][i])) {
                            matches++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        matches *= 2;
        res = matches / denominator;
    }


}
```

I have tried the above code for bigramizing the words in the file "input.txt" i have got the result of bigram but i didnt get the similarity value.
for e.g:
input file contains as

```
answer:
high
risk
simulate
behaviour
solution
set
rules
[2]
rules
outline
high
source
knowledge
[1]
set
rules
simulate
behaviour
```

in the above example I have to compare the words under answer with every word under [2] as {high,rules} {high,outline} {high,high} {high,source} {high,knowledge} and I have to store the maximum value of the above comparison and again the second word from answer is taken and then similar process is taken. At last, mean of maximum value of each iteration is taken.

Comment: describe at least as exactly as possible how the expected output should look like. the way things are described now it's difficult to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Ashalynd my output should be similarity value for eg the words {high,rules}{high,outline} {high,high} {high,source} {high,knowledge}, should be compared as bigram and the similarity value should be returned.Again next word "risk" should be taken and it should be compared as {risk,rules} {risk,outline} {risk,high} {risk,source} {risk,knowledge}   From that i have to take max similarity value and should take mean for overall answer from the maximum value which is stored for each word comparison.